# Linked-list remove() and index is not accurate

Tags: java, if-statement, indexing, linked-list

I was trying to delete all multiples of a chosen number from a linked list, like for example, removing multiples of 2:

[0, 12, 16, 0, 13, 9, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14] ->
[13, 9, 13, 17, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1]

I wrote this code to construct a linked list of 20 random integers and then, depending on the condition, remove elements from it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class MyList {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int entero = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        LinkedList<Integer> objectList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
            int randomInteger = random.nextInt(20);
            objectList.add(randomInteger);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 y 5: ");
        int intNumber = scan.nextInt();
        if(intNumber > 5 || intNumber < 1){
        }else{
            System.out.println("List : " + objectList);
            if(intNumber == 2){
                for(int j=0; objectList.size()>j; j++){
                    System.out.println("va " + objectList.get(j));
                    if (objectList.get(j) % 2 == 0) {
                        objectList.remove(objectList.get(j));;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final List : " + objectList);
    }
}
```

Problem with this is that it wont delete certain items, even though it should (e.g: condition 14%2==0 gets evaluated as true, but the number wont be removed), so the result ends up like this:

from [0, 12, 16, 0, 13, 9, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14] -> to [0, 13, 9, 13, 17, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 12, 14, 14]

Why is this not deleting all the multiples of 2 from the list?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Why not put all the elements in a set ? A set won't store any duplicates !!

Answer (score 2):

You're deleting list elements while iterating over it.
So, for example, after deleting the element with index 0, next iteration will point to objectList[1] which was objectList[2] before removal of objectList[0]. You can easily see it when debugging.

So you can for example create a list of elements to delete and then use removeAll(toDelete).

But as for me, the best way is to use stream api.

```
objectList.stream().filter(o -> o%2!=0).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

will return exactly what you need.

Update: I've just found, there's a `removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)` method.

So you can simply use

```
l.removeIf(o -> o % 2 == 0);
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are removing items from a list while iterating through the list. That's why it is not behaving the way you are assuming it would.

However, You can use the iterator.remove() method to solve your problem. In that case you have to iterate through an iterator. And the code might be as follows:

```
if(intNumber == 2){
        Iterator<Integer> iter = objectList.iterator(); 
        while (iter.hasNext()) { 
           if (iter.next() % 2 == 0) {
                iter.remove();;
           }
        } 
}
```

This should solve your problem. Let me know if you don't understand any part. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are removing items from a list while iterating through the list. That's why it is not behaving the way you are assuming it would.
You're deleting list elements while iterating over it. So, for example, after deleting the element with index 0, next iteration will point to objectList[1] which was objectList[2] before removal of objectList[0]. You can easily see it when debugging.

import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class MyList {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int entero = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        LinkedList<Integer> objectList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> removeObjectList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
            int randomInteger = random.nextInt(20);
            objectList.add(randomInteger);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 y 5: ");
        int intNumber = scan.nextInt();
        if(intNumber > 5 || intNumber < 1){
        }else{
            System.out.println("List : " + objectList);
            if(intNumber == 2){
                for(int j=0; objectList.size()>j; j++){
                    System.out.println("va " + objectList.get(j));
                    if (objectList.get(j) % 2 == 0) {
//                        objectList.remove(objectList.get(j));// do not remove element from here.
                        removeObjectList.add(objectList.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        LinkedList<Integer> finalList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(Integer num : objectList){
            if(removeObjectList.stream().noneMatch(it -> it.equals(num))){
                finalList.add(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final List : " + objectList);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You failed to account for the index of every element changing whenever you delete an element. The following is the output for the same test case you have given, except with a few print statements for the purpose of tracking the state of the list. This should make it clearer why your code is behaving as it is:

```
Enter a number between 1 y 5: 2
List : [0, 12, 16, 0, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 0
List : [12, 16, 0, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 16
List : [12, 0, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 1
objectList.get(j)%2 = 1
objectList.get(j)%2 = 1
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 12
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 12, 1, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 12
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 12, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 12
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 6, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 1
objectList.get(j)%2 = 1
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 6
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 1, 12, 5, 5, 1, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 12
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 14, 12, 14, 14]
objectList.get(j)%2 = 0
Deleting 14
List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 12, 14, 14]
Final List : [0, 13, 17, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 12, 14, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you iterate in positive direction over the List while deleting it's current position, therefore you jump over severall elements.

If you change your for loop to negative direction your code will work:

for(int j=objectList.size()-1; 0

So a final solution may look like (Code with small improvments):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyList  {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int entero = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int randomInteger = random.nextInt(20);
            integerList.add(randomInteger);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 y 5: ");
        int intNumber = scan.nextInt();
        while (intNumber < 1 || 5 < intNumber) {
            System.out.print(
                    "Youre entered number does not match the asked set, please enter number with matches mathematical set {x∈ℕ|1<x<5}");
            intNumber = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Random List : " + integerList);
        for (int j = integerList.size() - 1; 0 < j; j--) {
            if (integerList.get(j) % intNumber == 0) {
                integerList.remove(integerList.get(j));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final List, filtered out \"" + intNumber + "\" and its multiples: " + integerList);
    }
}
```